# Magento: How do I make products available to cart ONLY if you have something else inside already?

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, product, magento-rules

I'm trying to set up a magento shop, and basically I want certain products (add on items) only if they have the main product already in their cart.  I don't want the customer to be able to purchase the add on products on their own.

How would I set that up?

Comment: Would a Bundle Product work? Read more @ http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product?

Comment: I added my previous comment as a answer below so please accept it so that users don't keep on seeing it as an unanswered question and spend time reading it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this you could [Create a Bundle Product in Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product)